# Deploying to Heroku failed. rake is aborted b/c of Invalid CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

When I try and deploy to heroku using git push heroku master, the rake is aborted after trying to run 'Running: rake assets:precompile' followed by:

Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  box-sizing": expected "{", was "; border-box;"
       (in /tmp/build_b649c62b-25fd-47f5-b1bb 34c117e65124/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)(sass):21

followed by lines such as:
/tmp/build_e2651908-2c3d-4fc0-ba4a-5e0606acc0ef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1163:in `expected'

then the Precompiling assets failed. and the push is rejected.

Can anyone help?

The code I have in my application.css file on line 21 is as follows. do note that line 21 is between the two blocks of code.

```
* {
  background-color: rgb(65,140,190);
}

header {
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-style: dashed;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

Comment: @but there's no `box-sizing`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asterisk on the first line.  That shouldn't be there